# Display image using a scaling value on wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this markup in XAML:

```
<Canvas Width="250" Height="250">
    <Image Source="{Binding UserImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
</Canvas>
```

This is showing image with its original size (I don't know the size as it depend on userimage which is not available at design time)

I want to show it in say 1/10 of its original size. It is very important that the pixel size of the display image be exactly 1/10 of original image size.

How can I do this?

This is an MVVM application, and I prefer to do this in XAML instead of C# code if it is possible.

Comment: can you not set height and width to you image ? that should solve it unless you have dynamic requirements.

Comment: @Muds If I don't set the width and height of image, it shows in its original size, but I want to show it 1/10 of its original size.

Comment: i am suggesting you to set image's height and width, not canvas's. setting size to image will resize it.

Comment: @Muds: Can not do that, as It is only part of xaml as I need to show the relative size of different images and I like to draw them on the same canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried applying a scale transformation on the image? First, add the following to the `Image` control to enforce it being drawn in its original size:

```
<Image ... Stretch="None" />
```

Then apply a `LayoutTransformation` to scale the image down to 1/10 of the original size:

```
<Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding UserImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.1" ScaleY="0.1"/>
    </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have just put this in a comment, but I don't have enough rep. Can  you not just set the height and width on the `<Image>` tag instead of the `<canvas>` tag? or possibly use the MaxHeight and MaxWidth Property on the `<Image>` tag?